# Pinning Eclipse Icon onto Icons-Only Task Manager in Plasma 5

Tags: icons, kde, eclipse, plasma-5

How can I pin my Eclipse Neon icon as a launcher onto the *Icons-Only Task Manager* in Plasma 5? Pinning the **eclipse.desktop** file I have created onto the *Icons-Only Task Manager* doesn't really work.

I can launch Eclipse, but once the process is started, a new icon appears in the task manager.

Pinning this icon doesn't work at all. It just sits there and does not react to my clicks.

System Information: KDE Plasma 5.9.3, KDE Frameworks 5.32.0 built against Qt 5.7.1